# Need a method for base_url() or home_url() in CF7 additional settings

Tags: php, javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

For a redirect in CF7, on_sent_ok: "location.replace('https://www.mywebsite.com/pageid')" works well in the additional settings but I need to make my website more portable. I would like to use a function to call base_url() or home_url(). Instead of writing out http://www.mywebsite.com/pageid, I would rather use on_sent_ok: "function('pageid')."

I have tried adding a JS to the page template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PgRedirect($pageid) {
         var url=''
         url= "<?php echo home_url($pageid)?>";
         window.location = url;
</script>
```

This does not work. I have tried adding a function to functions.php:

```
function wpcf7_pg_redirect($pageid){
    wp_redirect(home_url($pageid));
    exit();
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_pg_redirect');
```

This does not work either. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the URL of any type of post, including pages, you should use [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) function, which returns the canonical URL of the post/page taken care of WordPress permalink configuration.

Using `home_url()` or `base_url()` to get a page permalink is bad idea because you can not be sure if you are getting the caninical URL of the page. Also, `home_url($pageid)` is wrong, `home_url()` accepts a path to be appended to the home url bu a page ID is not a path.

So, use `get_permalink()`:

```
echo get_permalink( $pageid );
```

If you are going to print it within inline JavaScript, you should use also [`esc_js()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_js) to escape the string. Or, if you are going to use it for a redirection, [esc_url_raw()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw):

```
function wpcf7_pg_redirect($pageid){
    wp_redirect( esc_url_raw( get_permalink( $pageid ) ) );
    exit();
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_pg_redirect');
```

Or, if you want it to work with the ajax request (filter suggested by @userauser):

```
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_json_echo', 'cf7_custom_redirect_uri', 10, 2);
function cf7_custom_redirect_uri($items, $result) {

    if ( $some_condition_is_true ) {

        $redirect_to = get_permalink( $pageid );

        $items['onSentOk'] = "location.replace('{" . esc_js( $redirect_to ) . "}')";

    }

}
```

Comment: You should improve my answer not copy it ad-hoc...

Comment: You and me answered almost at the same time, you used `home_url()` and I used `get_permalink()`. I included the `wpcf7_mail_sent` action example and you included `wpcf7_ajax_json_echo` filter.  After frist publish time, I edited the answer to include one more example, which I toke from your answer; I think there is absolutely no problem with that; just like you have done to include the `wpcf7_mail_sent` action example I published first. See the revision history.

Comment: The code example for the callback on `wpcf7_mail_sent` hook is a re-iteration of the OPs code, nothing to do with yours and it is to support my suggestion that it's often better to use `wpcf7_mail_sent` to issue your redirect if you know ahead of time where you want to redirect to or where no DOM action is required, so your point is moot. If you copy someone else's answer ad-hoc, credit that person, credit the source and explain why you are using it. Now we have two answers, one of which you copied, that send mixed message to readers as to the right one to use with no explanation.

Comment: I've credited you now for the `wpcf7_ajax_json_echo` filter suggestion, if you feel better. My answer was almost at time than yours, in fact I saw your answer after mine, and it was totally differnet from yours. It is a totallty legitimate answer.

Comment: ...that's why you improve answers as a good WPSE citizen. If you don't care, then you don't care about "answering" or that you just don't care about how you answer. Cool, now I know how you roll. All good, no love lost.

Comment: Again, see the revision history of both answers.

Comment: Of course your first answer was different (that's legit), you then copied my answer, which is fine if you do it properly. You're skirting the issue. Point I am making is, credit people where due, but more importantly improve other peopels answers because your information about `esc_js` is valuable regarding security.

Comment: Again, see the revison history. Your answer and mine are totally different, you want to use `home_url()` to get a  page URL, I suggest `get_permalink()` is the correct one; **that is the core of both answers and waht make them totally differents**. And, again and again and again, see the revision history.

Comment: `home_url` vs `get_permalink` is irrelevant, my logic is an example about using the filter, it's the context and theory behind that counts. All you need to do to add value is comment on my answer and say "or... use `get_permalink`. Revision history says nothing but you saw, you copied - that's it... which function is irrelevant, again. But I get it man, like you said you don't care, it's cool, no love lost. Let us move on compadre.

Comment: As far I understood the quesiton, that is what was asked. I read this problem: "how to use base_url() or home_url() to get a page URL". I consider that question a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because the correct answer for me is not to use `home_url()`, use `get_permalink()`. If I had understood the quesiton about some logic specific to CF 7 I had voted to close the question because third-party plugins are off-topic here. I'm going to stop this silly discussion right here. I have no problem at all, I hope you have not any with me.

Comment: "I hope you have not any with me..." <--- none what-so-ever, we're good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enqueing your own JS function in the DOM hoping to marry it with CF7's `on_sent_ok` functionality in an unorthodox manner, let's take a step back and filter the resulting JS that CF7 will pass through **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** represented as a string.

For example:

```
function cf7_custom_redirect_uri($items, $result) {

    if ( $some_condition_is_true ) {

        //build the url in which you wish to redirect to...
        $redirect_to = home_url('?p=123');

        $items['onSentOk'] = "location.replace('{$redirect_to}')";
        
    }

}

add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_json_echo', 'cf7_custom_redirect_uri', 10, 2);
```

In your (OP) example above, you are hooking onto `wpcf7_mail_sent` to issue your redirect, which in all cases is the way I would issue the redirect instead of worrying about the `eval()` nonsense that CF7 does. If you don't need to render anything else in the DOM before redirecting the latter is better in my opinion.

Example:

```
function wpcf7_pg_redirect(){

    if ( $some_condition_is_true ) {

        //build the url in which you wish to redirect to...
        $redirect_to = home_url('?p=123');

        wp_redirect(home_url($redirect_to));
        exit();

    }


}

add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_pg_redirect');
```

Note: in my examples  `$redirect_to = home_url('?p=123');` can be built anyway you want, programmatically, you do not need to hardcode `?p=123`.

So if you know the URL in which you wish to go to based upon some scheme or available variable or condition you would build the URL in accordance with that specification.

If you are having trouble building the destination URL, tell us exactly how you want to determine which URL you should redirect to...

- are you redirecting to the same page (like a refresh)?
- or are you redirecting to another page and if so what conditions need to be met that determine which page you redirect too?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your tips.  I did try them.  I found I was over complicating things in the process.  This ended up being my solution:

on_sent_ok: "location.replace(window.location.href.substring(0, (window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")) + 1) +  '[postid]');"

This gives me the home url and makes it possible to adjust to changes in that url when I try to port the site on other servers.

Comment: Very tricky solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is an even better solution based upon a shourtcode method found here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/linking-to-pages-within-site?replies=12

In functions.php add this:

```
// create shortcode for website's home page address: [url]

function myUrl($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "href" => home_url()
    ), $atts));
    return $href;
}
add_shortcode("url", "myUrl");
```

With this [url] works in this form:

on_sent_ok: "location.replace('[url]/pageid/');"

It also works on pages and posts.  Very useful.

Comment: Using a shortcode to pass values to JavaScript is very bad idea in general, really bad idea in my opinion, specially when you have hooks to do it properly like other answers has done. For example, you lost control over JavaScript dependencies.